# Datetime column in a dataframe is converted to unix time when I run the python script in Google Clouf Functions

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

When I trigger a python script in a local server via Airflow, the date column looks as it should in bigquery, but when I run this script in Google Cloud functions (versions of the libraries are same),The date column appears as unix time in the table. What could be the reason for this?

The part about the relevant column in the script:

```
df['Report Refresh Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Report Refresh Date']) # converts 'object' type to datetime
```

Output 1: (triggered script located in the local server via Airflow):

[image]

(It also appears in this format in bigquery when I upload as a parquet file)

Output 2: (triggered  script located in the Google Cloud Functions via Cloud Scheduler):

[image]

I expect the same result when I use Google Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Can you share the full code ?

Comment: I have solved this error with giving this parameter to the df.to_parquet():   use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this error with giving this parameter to the df.to_parquet(): use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True